# Best and fastest way to return an array from a map based on some condition

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

I'm trying to figure out the best and most efficient way for this scenario with a map. It needs to be an array. I've made a dummy example to explain this.

Basically if there is a map that consists of some sandwhich id and and sandwhich details and I only want the ones with lettuce to be in an array.

The problem with arrays is that the size must be known, in this case I do not know how many sandwhiches with lettuces there will be. I could use an array list but I would need to convert it to an array - some copy method which would make this inefficient.

Example:

```
//Assume that this map is given
Map<Integer, Sandwich> sandwiches = //some method gets all sandwiches
Meal[] meal = new Meal[sandwiches.size()];
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Sandwich> e : sandwiches.entrySet())
{
   if(e.getValue().hasLettuce())
        meal = new Meal(e.getValue);
}
//mandatory: An array must be returned
return meal;
```

Comment: I'm sure you mean `sandwiches.entrySet()`...

Comment: Since when does `Map` have a `hasLettuce` field? :)

Comment: @Zong Zheng Li Since today :) thanks for pointing that out. Also thanks Makota. I've edited the snippet

Comment: Code will not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList`. There's no way to avoid making copies if you don't know how many `Meal`s you'll need, the amortized cost of the copies is cheap, and lists are a better conceptual fit for the problem than arrays anyway. You can call `list.toArray(new Meal[0])` to get an array if you really want one.

Comment: Although the size of the array would be bounded by the size of the map, so you could get away with copying just once at the end to shrink the array. The amortized version performs exactly the same number of copies initially as it's a geometric sum, but one large allocation may be more efficient than many smaller ones (since OP cares about performance). Also the conversion from `ArrayList` to an array will most likely require another copy.

Comment: cool, I'm assuming that instead of of 'new Meal[0]' it would be 'new Meal[list.size()]' ?

Comment: `new Meal[list.size()]` works too, but it gives a minor risk that you'll accidentally say `new Meal[sandwiches.size()]` and then wonder why your array has a bunch of nulls in it somewhere down the line.